# Regex is not working in O365 Transport Rule

Tags: regex, office365, textpattern

I'm trying to create a custom sensitive information type in Office365to match a header pattern :

.+(spf=pass).+\n.+(dkim=pass))|((.+(spf=pass).+(dkim=pass))|(((spf=pass).+(dkim=pass))))

but i'm getting below error :

"You cannot configure a pattern with groups or multiple match conditions like (.*,.+,.{0,n} or .{1,n}. Remove the group or the multiple match condition from the pattern to continue."

How can i replace ".+" to any other matching pattern as we need this characters to match the pattern string

Comment: Pehaps you could try `.+(spf=pass)[\s\S]*?(dkim=pass)`

Comment: Try removing the 'outer' parentheses, keeping only those that are supposed to capture a group. It may be OK to have `.+`, just not between `(...)`.

Comment: Tried both solutions, but It still giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's the .+. You can't have it anywhere. I got around it with [\w\W]+ which basically is the same thing. You could also use [\s\S]+

See here for a list of the restrictions. I had different behaviour when the regex was in a condition or an exception too
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/create-a-custom-sensitive-information-type-in-scc-powershell#potential-validation-issues-to-be-aware-of